# non prime generated cyclic numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I recently watched a [numberphile video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUlaUalgxqI) on youtube talking about cyclic numbers. I was wondering if there was a number $1/a$, where $a$ wasn't prime, but $1/a$ turned out to be a cyclic number.

Or must $a$ always be prime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, if you want a number $\frac{1}{x}$, where $x$ is an integer, to be a cyclic number you need $x$ to be prime. In fact, it can't be just any prime number. The primes which generate these cyclic numbers actually have their own special names and are called full reptend primes. These cyclic numbers are heavily related to what are called repunits (where you have an integer consisting of only one digit which repeats) which are related to special primes called permutation primes (or absolute primes) as well as cyclic primes.

While it is necessary that the number in the denominator be primes, it is still unknown whether there exist an infinite amount of these cyclic numbers. But the question is related to another deeper problem in Mathematics called Artin's constant.

Comment: thanks! That just brought prime numbers another step center-ward in my brain's attention field.

Comment: No problem. These special classes of prime numbers are actually part of my research.

Comment: that's extremely interesting! I've always wondered about number theory but never had the chance or time to delve into it. I study electrical & computer engineering and it's really all about application :(